# Margin: 0px auto didn't work in apple safari

Tags: iphone, css, safari, mobile-safari

I have a construction that works well in all browsers except iPhone Safari, it sticks to left side though it's not supposed to.

.home{width: 980px; margin: 0px auto 0px auto;}

any advice?

Comment: UPDATE: img {display: block; width: 200px; margin: 0px auto} works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I don't think IPhone screen width is more 980px ^^

Comment: ya, 980px is greater than screen width, but others divs in my layout has the same width (I just checking the site output for iPhone that has no mobile version) and everything looks good except margin auto for width greater than screen width

Comment: How can margin:auto; center the elements if it is larger than its content ??

Comment: It isn't possible to center content that is wider then the screen. Have you ever seen a site where you can scroll left at the initial load? I have not.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it wasn't working because the parent element was a flex div that wasn't properly prefixed. Here follows the solution if you fall into the same situation:

```
.parent {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.child {
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```